# Constant speed of light implying photons to be in two places at the same time

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Here is a thought experiment for which I cannot find a good answer or explanation. Let us imagine that in the void and on a (very long) line there are two lights switched off in points A and C. Two observers are waiting in point B, at the same distance of A and C.

The experiment is such as at 12 PM in the reference frame of the line, the lights are switched on and off, so that they are both emitting a photon towards the point B. As the line is very long, one of the observer has enough time to move to a point B' on the line while the two photons are going towards the observers. After he has moved to point B', the observer stops and waits, and so now the two observers are both again at rest with respect to the reference frame of the line.

Finally, at some time, the photons reach point B. They cross at point B, as they were equally distant from this point when they left, and as they travel with constant speed. But they also reach, at some (other?) time point B', where they cross each other, as for the second observer they were equally distant from him when they left and as they travel with constant speed.

So we now have two photons crossing each other at some different places in the same reference frame of the line, which seems very weird given their trajectory. What truly happens?

Comment: DataXplorer, I implore you, please draw a spacetime diagram of this thought experiment. And this is generally good advice because often, in the process of drawing the diagram, you'll see the answer to your question.

Comment: Do you also believe that if the observer walks **past B**, he will continue to say that A and B are equally far from him, even though B is between him and A?

Comment: Your error is in assuming that the line has a reference frame. It doesn't. No acceleration is involved here. You simply have one static observer and one moving with a constant speed. They meet in the middle of the line. In their frames photons are emitted at different times. The one who sees them emitted simultaneously will receive them simultaneously as well. See Einstein's Train here, it is the same setup as yours well explained with a nice animation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity - I've removed the General Relativity tag, because it is not applicable to this case.

Comment: @safesphere The "reference frame of the line" is the reference frame that is stationary with respect to points A and B. It is incorrect to say that such a reference frame doesn't exist. If the observer "stops and waits" at B', acceleration is definitely involved (because acceleration is involved in stopping). And the relativity of simultaneity isn't especially useful here, since this entire thought experiment can be done in the non-relativistic regime, with slow-moving billiard balls instead of light, and you'd get the same qualitative behavior that the OP finds "weird".

Comment: @probably_someone Sorry, but I believe that your answer and comments are misleading.

Comment: @safesphere Yes, I actually came to the same conclusion than yours while discussing with probably_someone. But it seems this answer is not shared by everyone.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/554156/123208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This apparent paradox is resolved by relativity of simultaneity.

Consider observer O at rest relative to points A and C, and observer O' moving towards point A. Both observers are at point B, equidistant between A and C.

Photons are emitted simultaneously from points A and C. This statement, in a question about relativity, should immediately prompt the question "simultaneous in what frame?" For the photons to meet at point B, it must be simultaneous in the rest frame of observer O.

Observer O' is not at rest in that frame. In the rest frame of O', the photons are not emitted simultaneously. Instead, point A emits a photon before point C does. In fact, point A emits a photon before O' even reaches point B. By the time the observers meet at B, in the rest frame of O' point A has already emitted its photon. Point C then emits its photon in that frame some time after observer O' has passed point B.

In the rest frame of observer O, the photon from point A has less distance to travel to reach O', and therefore O' sees it first.

In the rest frame of observer O', the photon from point A travels the same distance as the photon from point C, but A's photon starts the trip earlier, and therefore O' sees it first.

Both frames agree that observer O' sees the photon from point A and then the photon from point C. They just have different reasons for the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Point B' is not the same distance away from A and C. Therefore, the photons will not reach point B' at the same time. The observer at B' will not see the photons cross; that observer will see one photon moving in one direction, and then, after some time delay, the other photon moving in the other direction.

Comment: If it was the case, this observer would see a photon go faster than the other. They left at the same time for him, from the same distance, and they go to the same speed towards him. Furthermore, he does not know he is moving : for him, the observer staying on point B is moving.

Comment: @DataXplorer After the observer moves to B', the photons are no longer the same distance from him.

Comment: If it was the case, they would not go with same speed from his point of view. This would contradict relativity. He can compute their speed by dividing the distance he was from them when they left, say d, by the time they took to reach him. As d is the same for both, if the speed of light is constant, it must be that they reach him at the same time.

Comment: there is only one point, $B$, on the line $AC$ that is equidistant from $A$ and $C$, so $B'=B$. If you disagree, please provide a diagram.

Comment: @DataXplorer Yes they would. One crosses a shorter distance in a shorter time, while the other crosses a longer distance in a longer time. Have you tried drawing a picture of this situation?

Comment: @DataXplorer The observer that moves from B to B' knows that he is moving, because he has to accelerate, and then decelerate, to do it. You can detect if you're in a non-inertial frame. Since he knows he's moving, he also knows that it's wrong to assume that he's still at B, which means that he knows that he is no longer equidistant from A and C.

Comment: @JEB Just imagine the problem from the point of view of the second obsever, the one "moving". From his point of view, he is not moving : he is seeing the lights and the other observer moving to the left when he goes to the right. So from his point of view, everything is exactly the same than for the first observer in B, from the point of view of this first observer.

Comment: @DataXplorer The moving observer has to accelerate, so he knows he's the moving one. Your body, for example, is a fairly good detector of changes in acceleration (this is why rollercoasters give you that particular feeling). Or, if you don't like that, we can build a simple device that can tell you if you're in an inertial frame: take a box with pressure sensors lining the walls, and put a ball floating in the middle of it. If the ball touches the walls, the box beeps. If you're holding the box and the box beeps, you know you're in a non-inertial frame.

Comment: @probably_someone I have an answer for that but it complicates unnecessarily the experiment. Assume the second observer is moving alongside the line at constant slow speed, crossing point B at 12 PM in the reference frame of the line. That way both observers are in inertial frames.

Comment: If he is moving (towards A)  at 12 PM, and is at B, then A has already emitted its light, and C has yet to do so, even though B has both flashing right then at the same time.

Comment: @DataXplorer Well, that's a completely different situation, but there is still no contradiction. In that situation, the moving observer (from the frame of the lights) has no reason to assume that A and C are equidistant from him at the time of measurement.

Comment: So if I understand well you say that length contraction and time dilation of special relativity solve the paradox if the second observer is not accelerating, and if he is I have to use the same concepts but with general relativity?

Comment: @DataXplorer No, length contraction and time dilation don't really have anything to do with it. It's just basic geometry. You said that the moving observer is moving slowly, so we can make him move slowly enough that the effects of time dilation and length contraction are completely ignorable. There is no contradiction even in Newtonian physics, because the moving observer is not equidistant from A and C when a photon hits him.

Comment: @probably_someone I would be satisfied with length and time modifications, but I do not understand your answer. He only has to be equidistant from A and B when the photons are emitted. Then as he does not know he is moving (and maybe he truly is not as he is in an inertial frame) the photons should reach him at the same time (if they have constant speed).

Comment: @DataXplorer As long as we're manipulating what the moving observer knows, how does he know that he's equidistant from A and B when the photons are emitted?

Comment: @probably_someone Because he knows that when he reaches point B (same as seeing the other observer, or reading the clock from the other observer showing 12 PM), the photons are emitted. This is how the experiment is implemented.

Comment: @DataXplorer Ok, so he knows his starting point, and he knows that A and C are equidistant from his starting point. He can also see that, from his frame, the other observer is moving, so at least one of them _must_ be moving relative to A and C. He then sees the two photons, at different times, and shouts to the other observer, "Hey! What did you see?" The other observer shouts back, "I saw two photons at the same time!" From this, the moving observer can conclude that the other observer was indeed stationary, and so he must be moving, so he's not equidistant from A and C. No contradiction.

Comment: @DataXplorer Or, if the two observers are completely unaware of each other, the thought process of the moving observer is as follows: "I know I started this experiment at a point equidistant from A and C. I have no idea whether or not I'm moving. If I'm not moving, then I will see two photons at the same time. If I am moving, then I will be somewhere else when one of the photons reaches me, and that point is not equidistant from A and C. Therefore, if I am moving, I will see one photon before the other." No contradiction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108352/discussion-between-dataxplorer-and-probably-someone).